# how do i open a pop up when some specific work is done?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am calling a function doCalculation which performs some calculation. After that I want to open a pop up window. How do I perform this task ?

Here is my code which is not working

```
function doCalculation(amount)
{
    var elm;
    elm = amount * 1 + 200 / 20;

    window.open('StaticPage.aspx?value=' + elm,'','toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=1000, height=200, top=100, left=100');
}
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong ?

Comment: You forgot to close your quote where the specs are. Does `StaticPage.aspx` already exist? I don't believe `copyhistory` is a valid spec.

Comment: its closed already. i just forgot it here. and yeah i removed copyhistory. still not working ?

Comment: Maybe you need to give the window a valid name (second param)? IIRC some browsers (like IE) have a problem with that.

Comment: if i move window.open at the beginning of the function it works. but i want to open it after calculation. so it means there is no error in syntax.

Comment: Seems to work fine in the Firebug console. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: pop up is not opening ? @MichaelTodd

Comment: But it works: http://jsfiddle.net/QykZP/ (You may need to allow popups at jsfiddle for it to work) What browser are you using?

Comment: i tried it on every browser like firefox, chrome, ie, opera. but its not opening. :(